# Pass a frame displaying the view as a command parameter?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I was wondering if you can pass a Frame which contains a control as a command parameter?

This is what I tried:

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Command="{Binding Path=SaveOptions}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Frame}}}"></Button>
```

However the parameter passed to the view model is null.  Can anyone sugest why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I can achive this is using `ElementName` attribute. But it is really interesting, why `FindAncestor` mode doesn't work.

Comment: Will ElementName still work even if the frame content is in a different XAML file?

Comment: No. And still, it's wired. Look visual tree [here](http://i058.radikal.ru/1107/ad/e958d9a9f0fb.jpg)